# Regular expression for links with no dot at the end

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to create a regex which matches links which have no dots at the end. I know a FQDN always has the root dot at the end, but I'm working on a blog service. I need to process blog posts and apparently some useres finish their post with with a link and then a dot to finish their sentence.

Those texts look something like:

`Example text... https://example.com/site. More text here...`

The problem here is that this doesn't link to any webpage. With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) I made this PHP function:

```
function modifyText($text) {
    $url = '/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/';
    $string= preg_replace($url, '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $text);
    return $string;
}
```

With the example from above this code generates

`Example text... <a href="https://example.com/site." target="_blank">https://example.com/site.</a> More text here...`

but it should generate

`Example text... <a href="https://example.com/site" target="_blank">https://example.com/site</a>. More text here...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to, at the end, lazy-repeat non-space characters, and lookahead for zero or more `.`s, followed by a space or the end of the string:

```
'/https?:\/\/[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(\/\S*?(?=\.*(?:\s|$)))?/i'
```

https://regex101.com/r/4VEWjW/2

Could also repeat dots followed by non-dots, to avoid being lazy:

```
'/https?:\/\/[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(\/\.*[^.]+(?=\.*(?:\s|$)))?/i'
```

Comment: This solves this problem but I've encountered a new one here. TLD can have more than 2 or 3 characters (I've set it to 9 for now) and URL's like `(https://example.longtld)` match the bracket too

Comment: Changing it to 9 indeed looks to work fine: https://regex101.com/r/4VEWjW/3

Comment: Similar to the second pattern, use a character set to match `.)`s, and then a negative character set to match anything but `.)\s`s at the end: https://regex101.com/r/4VEWjW/5

Comment: Your last comment doesn't work if the URL has a token after the last /

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\.)` after the `\S` to assert what is on the left is not a dot:

```
https?://[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*(?<!\.))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HxyZWR/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/kO6q5)

If you don't need the capturing groups `()` you could turn them into non capturing groups `(?:)`

You don't have to escape the forward slash `\/` if you use another [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) than `/` for example `~`

For example:

```
function modifyText($text) {
    $url = '~https?://[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*(?<!\.))?~';
    $string= preg_replace($url, '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $text);
    return $string;
}

echo modifyText("Example text... https://example.com/site. More text here... https://example.com/site");
```

Result

```
Example text... <a href="https://example.com/site" target="_blank">https://example.com/site</a>. More text here... <a href="https://example.com/site" target="_blank">https://example.com/site</a>
```

Comment: Works for the problem, but I've encountered another problem here, see discussion under the other answer, here is the example https://regex101.com/r/HxyZWR/2

Comment: You could create a character class `[.)]` to check if what is at the end is not a dot or a closing parenthesis https://regex101.com/r/HxyZWR/3